# Limit usage of memory without killing ECS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Is there any way to limit the usage of memory without killing ECS tasks? I've got multiple ECS tasks with different definitions on a single EC2 instance, where my Python applications are running on them. I set option, [memory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_memory) to hard limit usage of memory, however, it was resulted in killing a task with unwanted downtime. The solution doesn't have to be a setting on AWS but could be any mean, including limiting memory in the application layer.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the python program hits the memory limit?

Comment: @flakes, I don't have clear view on it, though I expected utilizing page cache from my python program if possible. You don't have to concern about time consumption by the way.

Comment: My follow up is more along the line of: do you want to limit memory consumption, or just gracefully handle the OOM?

Comment: I'm rather looking for a way to limit memory consumption than gracefully handling OOM. Because, I have different Python projects running on ECS tasks, which means I need to inspect where in the code large consumption is conducted for each project if I choose to gracefully handle OOM. I'm looking for a costless way aplyable to all projects to prevent from being killed.